# In google sheets, I am trying to find the most common string value related to another specific string value

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

In google sheets, I am trying to find the most common string value correlated to another string value. For example,

| Gender(A) | fav_lang(B) |
| --- | --- |
| male | python |
| female | java |
| male | rust |
| female | python |
| female | python |
| male | python |
| male | python |

I want to use some sort of function or group of functions to find the most popular coding language among females and just females.

I have tried several different functions but they were all meant for finding just the most common value in one column however I want to find the most common string value in a column based only if in another column, it states that they are female.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
=QUERY(CHOOSECOLS(A2:B8,1,2,2),"select Col2, count(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1")
```